# CoordinateCleaner function cc_sea() cannot access database from internet

Tags: r, dplyr, coordinates, spatial

I have been having this problem that doesn't exist for my colleagues that are using very similar code. I want to use the function cc_sea from the package CoordinateCleaner to check and flag points that exist in the ocean. For some reason, I cannot get this thing to work, and it seems to have trouble reading information from the internet, despite the fact that simply copying and pasting hte link it provides for that data seems to download a totally functional zip package. I decided to uninstall R and R Studio, and delete all of the folders that contained R program files and information about packages, and confirmed that when I reinstalled R 4.2.2 and RStudio that only its base packages were present. Below is some example code and the error:

```
#Example code:

library(CoordinateCleaner)
library(dplyr)


decimallongitude <- c(-99.21751470681781, -119.06093862146821)
decimallatitude <- c(19.270324424001558, 4.427074308059391)


data_cc <- data.frame(decimallongitude, decimallatitude)


data_cc %>% as_tibble %>% mutate(sea = cc_sea(., value = "flagged"))

#Output:

data_cc <- data.frame(decimallongitude, decimallatitude)
> data_cc %>% as_tibble %>% mutate(sea = cc_sea(., value = "flagged"))
Testing sea coordinates
trying URL 'http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/110m/physical/ne_110m_land.zip'
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  decimallongitude decimallatitude sea  
             <dbl>           <dbl> <lgl>
1            -99.2           19.3  NA   
2           -119.             4.43 NA   
Warning messages:
1: Problem while computing `sea = cc_sea(., value = "flagged")`.
i Gazetteer for land mass not found at
  http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/110m/physical/ne_110m_land.zip 
2: Problem while computing `sea = cc_sea(., value = "flagged")`.
i Skipping sea test
```

Answer (score 0):

Try (re)installing `rgdal`:

```r
install.packages("rgdal")
```

I attempted to get that dataset used by`cc_sea` directly with `rnaturalearth::ne_download()` and failed. It also failed with default values, but this time with a GDAL error and installing `rgdal` again fixed it for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, my code still runs the same error. I made sure to install the package and call it in as a library, after all of my other libraries, and it still has the same issue.